# Performing Network Operations in Android without the use of AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, http, user-interface

My question is a simple one, I'm looking for advice or links to a useful tutorial on multithreading and networking in Android. Every example I have looked at uses AsyncTask. What I want to know is can you get and use data just with threads and handlers?

I'm aware that the HTTP Request has to be done on a new thread otherwise you get NetworkOnMainThreadException but the reason I want to use threads and handlers is because i want the UI to be updated with said data from the other thread.

I'm not after code really, just pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Yes you can but why would you want to reinvent the wheel? Loot into the `AsyncTask` documentation what `publishProgress()` / `onProgress()`, `onPostExecute()` do

Comment: Alternatively, you can also look at this link https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html

Comment: AsyncTask is just a class that manages a background thread with event handlers for posting back to the UI thread. But creating a thread and then posting back using a Handler created on the UI thread isn't conceptually any different. So the answer to your question is yes you can.

Comment: The whole point of using AsycnTask is that is hides the complexity.  You are effectively asking "I know about AsyncTask.  Is there a more complex, difficult and bug prone way to achieve the same thing" ;)

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to know is can you get and use data just with threads and handlers?

Yes. The network operations just have to be done on a background `Thread` whether it be using `doInBackground()` of `AsyncTask` or creating a new `Thread`. Look at [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) and [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

> i want the UI to be updated with said data from the other thread.

No matter what you use, you still have to update the `UI` on the main `Thread`. This can be done very easily with `AsyncTask` using any of its other methods besides `doInBackground()` (`onPreExecute()`, `onProgressUpdate()`, `onPostExecute()` all run on the main `Thread`).

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

Network operations in Android can be done in any of the following ways.

1. Async Task
2. Intent Service
3. [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) or [CommonsWare's WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)

**When should i use each of this option ?**

1. Work should be done in ~1 second or less -  Async Task
2. Work may take more than 1 second but less than 10 seconds - IntentService
3. Work may take more than 15 seconds - WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 0):

Think that `Threads` are the same as a regular code, with the difference that they're run in background. So the question you have to ask yourself is: Can I use `Handlers` if I wasn't running `Thread`s? The answer is **yes**, you would just need to pass the Handler objects between the involved `Activities`, `Threads`, etc.

Now, if you want advices about what to choose. Keep in mind that `AsyncTask` is in fact an "improved" thread, but contrary to popular believings, it's not intended for very long running processes. For instance, if you want to have a thread running all your app life long, this is not the correct election. It's intended for tasks which have an end.

If you want to run long tasks, use a `Service`. It's a bit more confusing at the beggining, but that's the correct election. But be careful, a `Service` is not a thread! You might however put Threads inside it and treat them as they were running anywhere else.